# How can I choose 5 of my Twitter friends in a way that maximizes the number of distinct followers they have?

Tags: algorithm, twitter, computer-science

Assuming that I have an array of twitter users and their followers, and I want to identify 5 users who have the most number of unqiue followers such that if I ask them to retweet an advertisement for my product, it would reach the most number of users.

I do not have formal programming or computer science training. However I do understand algorithms and basic CS concepts. It would be great if a solution can be provided in a way a layman could follow.

Comment: Sort the array regarding the number of followers the users have, then take the first five.

Sorting is very easy because in most language it is already implemented.

Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Hmm. But if the top 5 users with the most followers have a large number of similar friends, then this method might not give me the optimal answer. I wish to identify users with the most unique followers so that my advertisement can have the greatest possible reach.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "Maximum coverage problem", which is a class of problems thought to be difficult to solve efficiently (so-called NP-hard problems). You can read about the problem on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem

A simple algorithm to solve it is to enumerate all subsets of size 5 of your friends, and measure the size of union of their followers. It is not an efficient solution, since if you've got n friends, then there's around n^5 subsets of size 5 (assuming n is large).

If you wanted a solution that's feasible to code and may be reasonably efficient in real-world cases, you might look at representing the problem as an "integer linear program" (ILP) and use a solver such as GLPK. The details of how to represent max-coverage as an ILP is given on the wikipedia page. Getting it working will require some effort though, and may still not work well if your problem is large.